# Differential of Lagrangian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

My professor wrote this $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\dot{q}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}})$. Due to the fact that I am very very very very bad at Math, could you explain me about this please? I don't understand.

$L(q,\dot{q},t)$ is the Lagrangian.

Comment: Can you say something more about your background? (math/phy/engine major, what courses did you take.....)

Comment: Are you asking about the Euler-Lagrange equation: $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q} = 0$, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler.E2.80.93Lagrange_equation

Comment: Sorry about that, John. I am taking Classical Mechanics Class, and the part I am asking about is Euler-Lagrangian. I can't figure out how to get from $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\dot{q}$ to $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}})$.

Comment: @Sopheak: As in Jared's comment, do you want to ask how the E-L equation is derived? I am not sure how to get your equality and it seems that it is not true in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the problem you are trying to solve is:

$$
S = \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathcal{L}(q, \dot{q}, t)dt
$$

Assume there is a particular function, $q_0(t)$, which minimizes* this integral.  We perturb this function and find the value of the integral with the perturbed functions:

$$
q(\eta, t) = q_0(t) + \eta \lambda(t)
$$

All that we require is that $\lambda(t_1) = \lambda(t_2) = 0$ (this function vanishes at the end points of the integral).  This gives, for any particular function $\lambda(t)$ that satisfies our boundary conditions:

$$
S(\eta) = \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathcal{L}(q_0 + \eta\lambda, \dot{q}_0 + \eta\dot{\lambda}, t)dt
$$

The tricky part (for me) is understanding that you can push the differentiation of $S$ inside of the integral:

$$
\frac{dS}{d\eta} = \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{d\mathcal{L}(q_0 + \eta\lambda, \dot{q}_0 + \eta\dot{\lambda}, t)}{d\eta}dt = 0 \\
\frac{dq}{d\eta} = \lambda, \frac{d\dot{q}}{d\eta} = \dot{\lambda}, \frac{dt}{d\eta} = 0
$$

This can also be confusing: why are are we trying to solve $\frac{dS}{d\eta} = 0$? The answer is that we're trying to find a critical point for the function $S(\eta)$, given some function $\lambda(t)$ (that satisfies our boundary values). What we find below is that $\eta$ drops out of the equation and thus also our extraneous $\lambda$ function. What we eventually find (assuming it's a minimum), is give some random $\lambda(t)$, this function $q(t)$ will give the "minimum" given the random $\lambda(t)$ function. We can find the "absolute" minimum by simply setting $\lambda(t) = 0$. We don't need to prove that $\eta = 0$ means a critical point--for one, we don't know what $q_0$ is, and second, the idea is that given *any* $\eta$ and $\lambda(t)$, this optimal $q(t)$ will give the "lowest" value!

$\eta$ drops out specifically because we've chosen $\eta$ to be a linear dependence--had we chosen $\eta^2$, this doesn't work. So then you ask, is this general? Well yes because we've allowed *any* $\lambda(t)$ function so long as it satisfies the boundary conditions ($0$ at both ends)--meaning it can do anything, even mimic $\eta^2$ between the boundaries!

\begin{align*}
\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{d\eta} =&\ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\frac{dq}{d\eta} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\frac{d\dot{q}}{d\eta} + \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{d\eta}\\
 =&\ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\lambda + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{\lambda} = 0
\end{align*}

$$
\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\lambda + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{\lambda}\right)dt = 0 \\
 \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{\lambda}dt = -\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\lambda dt
$$

Do integration by parts (i.e. the product rule) for the left integral:

\begin{align}
u =& \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}} & du =& \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right)dt \\
dv =& \dot{\lambda}dt & v =& \lambda 
\end{align}

$$
\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{\lambda}dt = \left.\lambda \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right|_{t_1}^{t_2} - \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}  \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) \lambda dt
$$

But we said $\lambda(t_1) = \lambda(t_2) = 0$ so the first part of this integral vanishes, leaving:

$$
\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{\lambda}dt = - \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}  \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) \lambda dt
$$

Substitute this back into the equation $\int\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{\lambda}dt = -\int\limits\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\lambda dt$

$$
- \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}  \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) \lambda dt =  -\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\lambda dt \\
\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}\right)\lambda dt = 0
$$

For this integral to be zero *for all* functions $\lambda$, the thing multiplying $\lambda$ must be zero, hence the [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler.E2.80.93Lagrange_equation):

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}\right) - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q} = 0
$$

*I say "minimize"--this is not correct. It's not even correct to say "find extremum". In reality, we're simply finding a function that is analogous to a critical point. And likewise, once we find such a function, we *must* verify it's the extremum we're looking for.

Comment: Very much Thank you. I can't tell you how much I am thrilled since you delighted me. Now I can understand a lecture.