# Minimize the definite integral over the selected time interval

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

**Problem:**

Find the value of $p$ such that:

$$\int_{0}^{t_{end}} \frac{d}{dt}e^{-p \cdot t}+(e^{-p \cdot t})^2 dt$$

is minimum.

**Attempt:**

I tried determine the derivative $\frac{d}{dp}$, directly expand the integral and equate to zero,i.e.:

$$\frac{d}{dp}\left(\int_{0}^{t_{end}} \frac{d}{dt}e^{-p \cdot t}+(e^{-p \cdot t})^2 dt\right)=0$$

but got an undecidable equation:

$$\frac{e^{-2 p t_{\text{end}}} -1}{2 p^2}-t_{\text{end}} e^{-p t_{\text{end}}}+\frac{t_{\text{end}} e^{-2
   p t_{\text{end}}}}{p}=0$$

but I am not sure if the above is a valid step. Even if it is, I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess, but this looks similar to an [Euler-Lagrange Equation Derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)

Comment: Yes, it seems. Is this the only known way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just get the integral, given $\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-pt}\right) = -pe^{-pt}$ and $\left(e^{-pt}\right)^2 = e^{-2pt}$, thus the integral is:

$$
\left.\left(\frac{-pe^{-pt}}{-p} - \frac{-pe^{-2pt}}{-2p}\right)\right|_0^{t_{\text{end}}} = e^{-pt_\text{end}} - \frac{1}{2}e^{-2pt_\text{end}} - \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

You can factor out $e^{-pt_\text{end}}$ out of that equation, and, I suspect, solve a for a minumum.

Hint:

\begin{align*}
f(x) =&\ e^{-x}  - e^{-2x} \\
f'(x) = &\ -e^{-x} + 2e^{-2x} = -y + 2y^2&\text{where } y = e^{-x}
\end{align*}

So $y = 0$ is a solution but $e^\zeta \neq 0$, so no $x$ there, but what about $y\left(-1 +2y\right)= 0 \leadsto -1 + 2y = 0 \leadsto y = \frac{1}{2}$?

Can you find a solution to $y = e^{-x} = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Is this the application of the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: but now try instead of $(e^{-p t})^2$ taking $(sech(e^{-p t}))^2$

Comment: @dtn No, not what I've said in this answer

Comment: and if the variational principle is applied?

Comment: @dtn $\text{sech}(x)$ is still an exponential...in particular, a negative plus/minus a negative exponential--you can still say $y = e^{x}$ or $y = e^{-x}$, etc. and solve.

Comment: I did not see the application of the variational principle here, because there it is looking, if I understood it correctly, a specific minimizing trajectory that changes in time. In my case, we need to define a constant n, which minimizes the difference. Can you demonstrate the solution to a problem using the principle of variation?

Comment: @dtn I suggest being more specific with your question. I hate to advertise my own answer, but, I did answer a question (quite a while back) where I went through the derivation of the [Euler-Lagrange Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746280/differential-of-lagrangian/746302#746302).

Comment: I will accept your answer as he, in general, solves the question that I posed.For the future, I want to ask, and if the integrand is more difficult, how to analytically solve such an optimization problem for it ...